# ajax data is getting null in controller function of MVC

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am beginner to ajax and MVC framework. I have to find mobile exist or not using ajax. I have tried following code.

**View**

```
if(mno.match(phoneno)){
//alert(mno);
 $.ajax({
              url: "/api/sales/existmobile",
              type:"POST",
              //ContentType: 'application/json',
             // dataType: "json",
              //async: false,
              //data:{'data': mno},
              //data:{data: JSON.stringify(mno)},
              data:{data: JSON.stringify(6547655566)},
              success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 console.log('success',data);
                    if(data === false){
                    alert('Mobile number already exists!');
                    $( "#custmobilenumber" ).focus();
                    }              
              },  
              error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log(textStatus);
              }
        });
}
```

**Route**

```
case "sales/existmobile":
            $sale = new Sale($data);
            $result = $sale->checkMobileExistSale($result);
            break;
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkMobileExistSale($result)
    {
        print_r($this->data);
        // $custMdl = new CustomerModel();
        //  $mobileExistResult = $custMdl->checkMobileExist($this->data);
        // return $mobileExistResult;
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function checkMobileExist($mobile){
        $sql          = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE mobile= :mobile';
        $placeholders = [':mobile'=>$mobile];
        $users = $this->select($sql, $placeholders);
        if (count($users) > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

When I print data of ajax passed in controller then its coming null. In inspect's Network(XHR)->Headers->form data, I can see data passed from ajax. But Network(XHR)->Response, its showing null.

I debugged with every possible way i could find with stackoverflow anwsers and google search but no use. I am not getting where the code is going wrong.

Please help and guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to execute checkMobileExistSale method without ajax and print the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a possible rectified code for your problem, I've mentioned the comments wherever necessary, see if it helps you. :) 
**Route**

```
case "sales/existmobile":
            $sale = new Sale($data);
            $result = $sale->checkMobileExistSale($data); // send $data here not $result
            break;
```

**Controller**

```
public function checkMobileExistSale($result)
    {
        echo $result;
        // print_r($result);
        // or try $result = $this->input->post();

        // $custMdl = new CustomerModel();
        //  $mobileExistResult = $custMdl->checkMobileExist($result); // send relevant data here
        // return $mobileExistResult;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Its working. It was actually route mistake. I have modified my code. But now if ajax response is true then its not coming out that if loop and not checking other conditions. What should I do? Please help in this also.

Comment: In your model check the value in `$users`, I think the query you're running is wrong.

Comment: from that query i am returning true/false and in ajax checking response. if its false then alert otherwise i have to say come out of the `if(mno.match(phoneno))` loop and check its else. thats not happening. if ajax returns true, i have written ` if (response == 'false') {
             alert('Mobile number already exists!');
                    $( "#custmobilenumber" ).focus();
        } 
        else if(response == 'true'){
            return true; // so that it will return from if(mno.match(phoneno)) but its not coming out
        }`

Comment: Please `echo $users` and see if it has any value, if no then your query is wrong, if yes then check the value in success by `console.log(data)` and see what's the data being returned by the `controller`.

Answer (score 2):

in ajax you are using post method then you have to use in controller

```
$this->input->post('data');
```

try this it will work for you